# what does /var/lib/update-rc.d/xxx for?

Tags: 12.04, directory

I find there are some files in `/var/lib/update-rc.d/`, such as:

```
$ more /var/lib/update-rc.d/exim4
update-rc.d exim4 defaults
```

the only content is a `update-rc.d` command add service to default level.

so, what does these files used for? and can they be deleted?

Answer (score 1):

`update-rc.d` command is a perl script:

```
$ file `which update-rc.d`
/usr/sbin/update-rc.d: a /usr/bin/perl script, ASCII text executable
```

I'm not good at perl, but from what I understand and its variable name:

```
my $archive = "/var/lib/update-rc.d";

sub save_last_action {
    my ($script, @arguments) = @_;

    return if $notreally;

    open(FILE, ">", "$archive/${script}.new") || die "unable to write to $archive/${script}.new";
    print FILE join(" ","update-rc.d",@arguments), "\n";
    close(FILE);
    rename "$archive/${script}.new", "$archive/${script}";
}

sub remove_last_action {
    my ($script) = @_;
    unlink "$archive/$script";
}
```

it just record the last action(command) of update-rc.d. and delete with no influence

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly not without risking breaking something. From `man file-hierarchy`

```
   /var/lib
       Persistent system data. System components may place private data 
       in this directory.
```

Which means they probably expect to find it. Don't delete them unless you know how to back up your system. We get enough "Hi, I just did $SOMETHING_REALLY_STUPID, how do I restore my machine to its previous state?" questions around here.

You might run `du -hs /var/lib/update-rc.d`. You'll probably find the space consumed is trivial.